# How to fix Dead or Stuck pixels on my android phone using PC?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I currently have fully covered black screen on my phone and it started from a small black spot and it spread. I don't know if its whether it is a dead pixel or stuck pixel. the phone is still functional just no display. How do i fix this using my PC?

Comment: I really don't think it is possible to recover it if its dead pixel as its a hardware problem so i highly doubt that some pc tweaks would solve it, if you can elaborate how it started and some images of current state people might be able to help properly

Comment: @HarshGundecha , well an image might not help at all since its just my phone with black screen but the phone still functional as in still receive notifications and connected to wifi. And the phone is Oppo R7 lite. But yea, i think its a dead pixels so im just gonna buy a new phone i guess... thanks for trying to help

Comment: You can get pixel fixers but it sounds like your whole screen has gone, It's probably a problem with the cable connecting the screen to the motherboard of your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked how to fix it using your PC, so here's the steps to follow:

1. Load up Google Maps on your PC.
2. Search for phone repair shops.
3. Find a result that's easy to get to and take your phone there.
4. Tell them your phone screen is broken and needs replacing.

If this started with a new phone, you should instead take it back to where you bought it, tell them they sold you a faulty phone, and ask them to replace it for you. Your PC isn't involved in this case.

Comment: i guess this will probably the best answer i could get for this problem. thanks